# Modifying field values of shapefile based on values in another table?

Tags: arcpy, forest-ecology

I have a shapefile containing 500+ polygons. Included in this file is a unique ID for each unit, an area (in acres) and an attribute indicating whether that unit can be modified or not (1 or 0). I also have a table that consists of a list of those same unique IDs and a score. I would like to produce a python script to do the following:

1. Identify the 10% of the total area that has the highest score.
2. Create a new field in the shapefile that indicates (with 1 or 0) whether that unit is part of that top 10%.

In order to do this, it is necessary to match the units with their corresponding scores, and then sort them by highest score. I then scroll down through the units, assigning them a value of '1' until the cumulative area exceeds 10%, and then assign the rest '0'.

I am accustomed to making these calculations in R, but this is my first time trying to automate this in Python (I need to do it 36 times). I am 100% positive there is a more efficient way to code this, but here is my current attempt that works as expected:

```
import numpy as np
import arcpy

# parameters are path to shapefile, path to table, proportion reserved, and proportion treated
def assign_tom(map, table, propt, propr):

# just some labeling to keep the scenarios straight
if propt == .1:
    t = "Ten_T"
elif propt == .2:
    t = "Twe_T"
elif propt == .3:
    t = "Thi_T"

if propr == 0:
    r = "No_R"
elif propr == .1:
    r = "Ten_R"
elif propr == .2:
    r = "Twe_R"
elif propr == .3:
    r = "Thir_R"

scen_code = r + "_" + t

treatable_col = "trt_" + r

# create field for whether unit will be treated under this scenario
arcpy.AddField_management(map, scen_code, "SHORT")

# create class to hold info for each stand
class Stand:
    def __init__(self, id, area, tom_score, cum_area, treatable, treat):
        self.id = id
        self.area = area
        self.tom_score = tom_score
        self.cum_area = cum_area
        self.treatable = treatable
        self.treat = treat

# create empty list to hold all the stands
stands = list()

# use search cursor to extract stand info, then remove it
features = arcpy.SearchCursor(map)

# use a counter to calculate total area for the shapefile as well
total_area = 0

for feature in features:
    x = Stand(feature.ID, feature.Acres, 0, 0, feature.getValue(treatable_col), 0)
    stands.append(x)

    total_area = total_area + feature.Acres

del features
del feature

# use search cursor to extract T.O.M. score from table
scores = arcpy.SearchCursor(table)
scores_list = list()

for row in scores:
    scores_list.append(row.MEAN)

# both map and list are ordered by ID, so they match up directly
# assign scores to each stand in the stands list
for index in range(0, len(stands)):
    stands[index].tom_score = scores_list[index]

# sort stands list by score in descending order
stands.sort(key = lambda x: x.tom_score, reverse=True)

# calculate critical value for cumulative area
crit = total_area * propt

# Scroll through stands, assigning them a '1' value for treat attribute
# if they are treatable and the cumulative area is less than critical value
area = 0

for stand in stands:
    if stand.treatable == 1:
        stand.cum_area = area
        area = area + stand.area

        if stand.cum_area < crit:
            stand.treat = 3
        else:
            stand.treat = 0

# sort stands again by ID
stands.sort(key = lambda x: x.id)

# now create updateCursor
field = [scen_code]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(map, field) as cursor:
    counter = 0
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = stands[counter].treat
        counter = counter + 1
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Basically, I create a Class (Stand) to temporarily hold the data for each unit. Then I use a SearchCursor once each on the shapefile and the table to populate a list of the units. I sort and resort the list containing the units, make the calculations, and then use UpdateCursor to change the values of the field.

What is a better solution to this problem? I don't want to create more fields than necessary in the shapefile, so my novice thinking tells me I need a way to temporarily hold the data while I sort it and make the calculations based on area.

Comment: What's wrong with your solution that makes you think you need a better way?  Arcpy/python can hold data in dictionaries etc. for you to do whatever you need to them before writing them back to your shapefile, or you have the option of using `in_memory` workspaces for storing spatial data temporarily, which are much faster for editing/processing, also before writing back to your shapefile

Comment: Minor comment:  I see you used a da updatecursor but 'old fashioned' searchcursor.  There is a da searchcursor as well.

Comment: @Midavalo I guess it just seemed repetitive to me, having to scroll through the data twice (once to read some of the fields, then again to update one field). And I am wondering if storing data from an attribute table as a list of objects (objects of a new class I created) is the best way for doing calculations like this in Python.

Comment: Check the indentation in your `def assign_tom(map, table, propt, propr):` function

Comment: It sounds like you are seeking a code review.  For that there is the [codereview.se] Stack Exchange.  Our advice when seeking GIS code reviews is at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4304